# Making Tridiagonal matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a triadiagonal matrix with matlab, using

```
full(gallery('tridiag', 10,  1, -4, 6, -4, 1))
```

and i take that i have too many arguments in the function. Is there another way to do this?

I am trying to make the following matrix:

```
 6    -4     1     0     0
-4     6    -4     1     0
 1    -4     6    -4     1
 0     1    -4     6    -4
 0     0     1    -4     6
```

Comment: Please explain what that code is supposed to do. What matrix should be created?

Comment: The inputs following `tridiag` must be 3 vectors but in your case you have 6 scalars. As @Daniel suggested, please give an example of the output matrix you wish to create

Comment: i tried to make the matrix in the question above @Daniel Thats for n = 5. i need to make it for n= 10, 100 and 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are 5 non-zero diagonals this is not a tridiagonal matrix so you cannot use the `tridiag` option. You have to manually generate such matrix by means of the `diag()` function, which allows you to create a matrix with a given diagonal and you can as well select which diagonal you want to write.

You can achieve this therefore by creating 5 different matrices, each of them will have a given non-zero diagonal:

```
n=5;
B=diag(6*ones(n,1),0)+diag(-4*ones(n-1,1),1)+diag(-4*ones(n-1,1),-1)+diag(1*ones(n-2,1),2)+diag(1*ones(n-2,1),-2);
```

In this code `n=5` is the order of your matrix, then `diag(6*ones(n,1),0)` will create a vector (length `n`) with all `6` and such vector will be placed in the 0-th diagonal. Such matrix will have zero elsewhere.
Similarly `diag(-4*ones(n-1,1),1)` will create a vector (length `n-1`) with all `-4` and such vector will be placed in the 1st superdiagonal. Such matrix will have zero elsewhere and we sum such matrix to the previous one.
And such "chain reaction" goes on until the matrix is fully generated.

**Update**: I've been looking around the `gallery()` help and there is indeed an option for a Toeplitz pentadiagonal. You might want to use then

```
full(gallery('toeppen',5,1,-4,6,-4,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alessiox :)

Comment: You're most certainly welcome @LauraA.Agalioti. However, as far as I can see in the comments above, for large `n` you might want to use @TroyHaskin 's solution. The `toeppen` solution works only for pentadiagonals and the "manual" solution can only work inside a for-loop (I reckon you agree at `n=100` it is indeed rather annoying to write manually the sum of all `diag()`s). @TroyHaskin 's solution is much smarter, `spdiags()` is actually a nice catch!

Answer (score 5):

Since your matrix is [pentadiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix), I think the best solution is to use [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html):

```
>> n = 5;
>> full(spdiags(ones(n,1)*[1,-4,6,-4,1],[-2,-1,0,1,2],n,n));
ans =
     6    -4     1     0     0
    -4     6    -4     1     0
     1    -4     6    -4     1
     0     1    -4     6    -4
     0     0     1    -4     6
```

The [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) is optional and not recommended for large `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that for your huge case a sparse-based solution such as that of [Troy Haskin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166229/5067311) is best. However, it's worth noting that you're precisely constructing a Toeplitz matrix (as [Alessiox hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166217/5067311)), and you can use the built-in [`toeplitz()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) to do that. All that is needed is to figure out the number of zeros needed for padding the input nonzero elements of the first row and column (this is necessary since `toeplitz` asserts the size of the matrix to construct from the dimensions of the input vector):

```
n = 5;                            %// linear size of result
v = [1,-4,6,-4,1];                %// nonzero diagonal elements symmetrically
mid = ceil(length(v)/2);          %// index of diagonal in the input vector
zerosvec = zeros(1,n-mid);        %// zeros for padding the rest
colvec = [v(mid:-1:1), zerosvec]; %// first column of the result
rowvec = [v(mid:end), zerosvec];  %// first row of the result
toeplitz(colvec,rowvec)           %// toeplitz does the heavy lifting
```